# garbage collecting variables in angularjs service

Tags: javascript, angularjs, garbage-collection, angularjs-service

I am new to angularjs. I have designed an angularJS service, which is as per the diagram given below :-

[image]

Global Service is used as a mean for inter-controller communication. That's, it contains data shared between parent and child controller. Grand Parent controller opens a popup dialog which has parentController2, which in turn open another popup, which has childController3.

Now, What I want is, data stored in global service must be set to null, when its associated controller is destroyed. It's because services are singleton in angularjs, as per my knowledge. So, I don't want service to hold variable throughout the life-cycle of application, even if they are not required.

Moreover, I am using controllerAs syntax and don't want to use $scope(I know that I can do garbage collection in '$destroy' event on scope), to make my stuff compatible with angularjs 2.0.

Is there any way, I can garbage collect variable in service, which are not required, from controller, when controllerAs syntax is used ?

Apologizing for newbie question. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

using ng-view is one more solution over here for garbage collection as it destroy's the scope as soon as view is changed. It will be used with ngroute but still provides better mechanism for garbage collection. 
You can check the ng-view code

```
 function destroyLastScope() {
    if (lastScope) {
      lastScope.$destroy();
      lastScope = null;
    }
  }
```

This function is called inside the directive that destroys the scope of the previous scope i.e if you go from parent to child the parent scope will be destroyed

Comment: What is lastScope here ?

Comment: it's the scope of the parent if you are moving to child.